# Should we remove facebook app-generated requests?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook app-generated requests for sending notifications to users. I  noticed that the notification is going away once the user logs in into the application. Does the requests get deleted automatically? I mean, without performing any action on the request ids. We used to delete those requests in the case of user-generated requests. Is it mandatory to delete it in the case of app-generated requests also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is the Developers' responsibility to delete a Request once it has been accepted. For more information on how to delete a Request, please see the Deleting Requests documentation.

[source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

That means yes, you have to delete all the requests after they're used